# Java: Something is wrong with my split method

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, lexer

I am trying to create a split method to split a line read in from an input file into an array of strings that I return. The problem is when I send in the line such as "ho;hi hello" through the for loop it always stops after the first delimiter or `";"` or the first operator such as `"+"`. I'm not sure why it is doing that as I'd like for it to keep iterating through until the end of line, meaning after the if statements iterate once again the for loop until `i < line.length()`

```
If String line =="ho;hi hello"
```

I'd like for it to print out

```
This is the string in location 0: ho
This is the string in location 1: ;
This is the string in location 2: hi
This is the string in location 3: hello
```

Currently it is only printing out

```
This is the string in location 0: ho
This is the string in location 1: ;
```

Always stopping at the first delimiter or operator. Here is the code for the split method.

```
private static String[] split(String line) {

    String temp = "";           //var to store each line from input temporarily 
    boolean flag = false;       //var to check if "\" is in the from input
    char[] lineCharArray = line.toCharArray(); //transforms line into array of chars  
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList to store the split strings temporarily

    for (int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++){
        if (!isDelimiter(lineCharArray[i]) && !isOperator(lineCharArray[i]) && flag==false){
            //System.out.println(lineCharArray[i]);
            temp += lineCharArray[i];
        } else {
            array.add(temp);
            if (isDelimiter(lineCharArray[i])) {
                array.add( String.valueOf(lineCharArray[i])); 
            }
            if (isOperator(lineCharArray[i])) {
                array.add( String.valueOf(lineCharArray[i])); 
            }
        }
    }


    String [] strings = new String[array.size()]; //string that is returned for lexical analysis
    array.toArray( strings );
    for (int i = 0; i<strings.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("This is the string in location " + i + ": " + strings[i]);
    }
    return strings;
}


  private static boolean isDelimiter(char c) {
     char [] delimiters = {':', ';', '}','{', '[',']','(',')',','};
     for (int x=0; x<delimiters.length; x++) {
      if (c == delimiters[x]) return true;      
     }
     return false;
  }

  private static boolean isOperator(char o) {
     char [] operators = {'+', '-', '*','/', '%','<','>','=','!','&','|'};
     for (int x=0; x<operators.length; x++) {
      if (o == operators[x]) return true;      
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: Why can't you split on `;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 3 issues over here.

1. SPACE is not a delimiter so expected output will be:

   ```
   This is the string in location 0: ho
   This is the string in location 1: ;
   This is the string in location 2: hi hello
   ```
2. You need to reset `temp` before adding any new char to it. Better use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.
3. You need to add last `temp` to the array as well.

Here I am providing modified `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++){
    if (!isDelimiter(lineCharArray[i]) && !isOperator(lineCharArray[i]) && flag==false){
        //System.out.println(lineCharArray[i]);
        temp += lineCharArray[i];
    } else {
        array.add(temp);
        // Resetting temp variable.
        temp = "";
        if (isDelimiter(lineCharArray[i])) {
            array.add( String.valueOf(lineCharArray[i]));
        }
        if (isOperator(lineCharArray[i])) {
            array.add( String.valueOf(lineCharArray[i]));
        }
    }
}
// Adding last temp to the array.
array.add(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not including ' ' as a delimiter.  Also, you need to reset temp to "" after you add it to array.