# Java: Extra white spaces in String arraylist when added using split method

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, lexer

I am trying to create a split method to split a line read in from an input file into an array of strings that I return. The problem is when I send in the line such as

> (;world 2013/05 // end

I'd like for it to print out

```
String in position 0: (
String in position 1: ;
String in position 2: world
String in position 3: 2013
String in position 4: /
String in position 5: 05
String in position 6: / 
String in position 7: / 
String in position 8: end
```

ignoring white spaces. Currently, however, it is printing out

```
String in position 0: 
String in position 1: (
String in position 2: 
String in position 3: ;
String in position 4: world
String in position 5: 2013
String in position 6: /
String in position 7: 05
String in position 8: 
String in position 9: /
String in position 10: 
String in position 11: /
String in position 12: 
String in position 13: end
```

I don't understand why there are extra white spaces added into my array list. Same error occurs if I use any other operators from my isOperator method ex:`+, -, *`

Here is the code for the split method.

```
private static String[] split(String line) {
    String temp = "";           //var to store each line from input temporarily 
    boolean flag = false;       //var to check if "\" is in the from input
    char[] lineCharArray = line.toCharArray(); //transforms line into array of chars  
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList to store the split strings temporarily

    for (int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++){
        if (!isDelimiter(lineCharArray[i]) && !isOperator(lineCharArray[i])){
            temp += lineCharArray[i];
        } else {
            array.add(temp);
            temp = "";
            if (isDelimiter(lineCharArray[i])) {
                if (lineCharArray[i] == ' ') {
                    continue;
                }
                array.add( String.valueOf(lineCharArray[i])); 
            }
            if (isOperator(lineCharArray[i])) {
                array.add( String.valueOf(lineCharArray[i])); 
            }
        }
    }
    array.add(temp);

    String [] strings = new String[array.size()]; //Dynamic allocation of array strings
    array.toArray( strings );
    for (int i = 0; i<strings.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("String in position " + i + ": " + strings[i]);
    }
 return strings;
 }

  private static boolean isDelimiter(char c) {
     char [] delimiters = {':', ';', ' ', '}','{', '[',']','(',')',','};
     for (int x=0; x<delimiters.length; x++) {
      if (c == delimiters[x]) return true;      
     }
     return false;
  }

  private static boolean isOperator(char o) {
     char [] operators = {'+', '-', '*','/', '%','<','>','=','!','&','|'};
     for (int x=0; x<operators.length; x++) {
      if (o == operators[x]) return true;      
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide a `main` method so we can test it easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is `temp` can be empty (it's empty to start with)

So while...

```
if (!isDelimiter(lineCharArray[i]) && !isOperator(lineCharArray[i])) {
```

Equates to `false`, you keep adding an empty `temp` value to your `List`.

To fix it, you could check to see if `temp` is empty before adding it...

```
} else {
    if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
        array.add(temp);
        temp = "";
    }
```

You're also missing the `' '` deilimitere

```
char[] delimiters = {':', ';', '}', '{', '[', ']', '(', ')', ',', ' '};
                                         Missing me ---------------^
```

Which I think was mentioned in [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987677/java-something-is-wrong-with-my-split-method)

So, after those few changes, I get this output

```
String in position 0: (
String in position 1: ;
String in position 2: world
String in position 3: 2013
String in position 4: /
String in position 5: 05
String in position 6: /
String in position 7: /
String in position 8: end
```

This is a basic process of using a debugger, so you can walk the execution of the code in real-time and see what's actually going on with your variables.